# how does printFun(1) calls printFun(2)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion

```py
def printFun(test): 
    if (test < 1): 
        return
    else: 

        print( test, end = " ") 
        printFun(test-1) # statement 2 
        print( test, end = " ") 
        return
test = 3
printFun(test)
```

Can anyone please explain the working of this algorithm after calling `printFunc(0)`

Comment: Please search up recursion. There are many tutorials on this topic.

Comment: "how does printFun(1) calls printFun(2)" - it doesn't. It's not clear why you thought it did. Also, you're calling `printFun(3)`, not `printFunc(0)`.

Answer (score 2):

I'll help break this code down for you.
First,

```py
if (test < 1): 
   return
```

I assume you know that this means that if `test` is smaller than 1, the function returns a value and terminate

```py
printFun(test-1)
```

Calles the function `printFun` again. This is called recursion. There are many good tutorials on this and it's considered a programming fundamental by many.
Basically, what is happening, printFun is being run again, but this time, the test paramenter is decreased by 1 . Any code below this line then waits for the function to execute again. Since `test` keeps decreasing by 1, eventually, it will be smaller than 1, and the function will terminate, which will cause the code beneath the function call to execute.

Looking at the last two lines, `test` is set to three and the function is called with a 3.

- Since `test` is not smaller than 1 and equal to 3, `3` will be printed to terminal
- Next, `printFun` is called again, but this time with `test-1`, which is 2
- Since `test` is not smaller than 1 and equal to 2, `2` will be printed to terminal
- Next, `printFun` is called again, but this time, with `test-1`, which is 1
- Since `test` is not smaller than 1 and equal to 1, `1` will be printed to terminal
- Next, `printFun` is called again, but this time, with `test-1`, which is 0
- Since `test` is smaller than 1 and equal to 0, the function terminates and returns
- There is still code after the recursion call where `test == 1`. Since test is equal to 1, `1` is printed to terminal, and then the function terminates
- There is still code after the recursion call where `test == 2`. Since test is equal to 2, `2` is printed to terminal, and then the function terminates
- There is still code after the recursion call where `test == 3`. Since test is equal to 3, `3` is printed ot terminal, and then the function terminates.
- We are now back to the initial function call.

Answer (score 1):

Let me unroll the code execution for your understanding of the recursion:

calling printFun(test=3):

> inside printFun(test=3)
>   (test < 1) is False
>   print(test) # 3
>   calling printFun(test-1) # the value 2
>
> > inside printFun(test=2)
> >     (test < 1) is False
> >     print(test) # 2
> >     calling printFun(test-1) # the value 1
> >
> > > inside printFun(test=1)
> > >       (test < 1) is False
> > >       print(test) # 1
> > >       calling printFun(test-1) # the value 0
> > >
> > > > **inside printFun(test=0)**
> > > >         **(test < 1) is True**
> > > >         **exiting printFun(test=0)**
> > >
> > > print(test) # 1
> > >       exiting printFun(test=1)
> >
> > print(test) # 2
> >     exiting printFun(test=2)
>
> print(test) # 3
>   exiting printFun(test=3)

So the output should be:
`3 2 1 1 2 3`
The second half being displayed after test reaches zero (which stops the recursion from going deeper).

So to answer your question, printFun(1) does not call printFun(2). **What happens is printFun(1) finishes executing before its parent printFun(2).**

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

It's name is recursion and if you have a good break condition like  if test < 1 it will do it job done without infinite loops